# How do I use a smartphone/tablet as a microphone for the Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi-desktop

I have my own Samsung tablet and i also own a Raspberry Pi 3, and I use the Raspberry Pi 3 as a daily driver and also have a very small YouTube channel with around 20 subs. I need a microphone so I can talk and do not want to spend over 20 USD maximum price. Is there a way I can get an application or cord to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Last time I got Android to pipe audio out to a Linux device I had to use Pulse Audio's network options, which was sub-optimal (*crackly* and *poppy*), I wasn't able to get mic. support, and it required root. At the time it wasn't worth looking into further, but I might be able to resurrect the notes.

One option in the meantime shown by [instructables](https://www.instructables.com/id/Use-your-smartphone-mic-with-your-PC/) would be to pipe things over an aux-cable instead, however, that also has latency issues. And I'm not certain that it wouldn't require a separate bit of hardware to get your RPi *listening* over such a connection.

So at this time I'd suggest recording audio via a voice recorder application, then transfer it over to your RPi for merging into the video during editing. Though I'm hopeful that someone'll come along and suggest something more CPU agnostic than [WO Mic](http://www.wirelessorange.com/womic/wo_mic_linux.html#div_setup). Which brings up one question I had, what software are ya using for video editing on RPi?